# Validating a set of dates in Microsoft Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, date-time, validation, datepicker

I am trying to validate dates in a task request form that has a column of [**Date of Request**] (which would be the day that they are adding the task to the main hub.

I, then, want that [**Date of Request**] to see the [**Requested Posting Date**] column and not allow it to post a date that is before the [**Date of Request**].

I have tried everything I can from:

```
=[Requested Posting Date]<=[Date of Request]
```

to

```
=[Requested Posting Date]<[Date of Request]
```

to

```
[Due Date] > [Created]
```

and none of those work for what I am trying to do here. I am doing all of these formulas in the validation settings section if that helps. Please help me if you can everything I try fails or just doesn't do anything, let me know how to resolve this and get it working. Just nothing will affect the date pickers whatsoever they do exactly the same thing no matter what formula I throw in, im completely lost, let me know Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the validation settings on the list settings page? (List Settings --> Validation Settings) Because that is the only one that allows you to compare 2 columns.

Comment: Yes I am writing these formulas on the list settings --> Validation settings  --> Formulas.  I haven't added any formulas to the column validation either and still nothing will be affected at all from the formulas I put in the validation settings area... Any ideas?

Comment: Is the column type for both the columns "Date and Time"?

Comment: Date of Request: Date and Time 
Requested Posting: Date and Time

Comment: Then, the second formula you posted, should definitely work i.e. =[Requested Posting Date]<[Date of Request] . I have just tested it.

Comment: Yes they are both column types of Date and Time but both are set to Date Only. Also Date of Request has Today selected under the default value section...Not sure if that would hurt me here, just gotta get it fixed so when I select a day for say Date of Request as today, I than need to have requested posting date be at least 24 hours from the first date on date of request, let me know what I can do...Thanks!

Comment: I just tried to do exactly that and it is not working on my side at all, everything is still working exactly as it was before... any ideas on what issue that might be, yeah just tried again and nothing over here....

Comment: What would or could be preventing these formulas from working if that one you said should have worked.... Really confused now?

Comment: Do you have any custom code/ solution installed on your sharepoint instance?

Comment: Nope! I don't! Just checked all the column validation stuff again and nothing is in there either....

Comment: Try this: Add this validation and see if the validation fires  =IF(Title="",TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: Do I add that under the List settings ---> Validation Settings --> Formula area...doing it right now. I will let you know what happens?

Comment: I just added that and nothing at all changed I don't believe...?

Comment: Any idea why it wouldn't do anything from that formula you just gave me or what should have happened?

Comment: For some reason, validations are not running at all for you. I will let someone else answer.

Comment: Anyone? I am just very confused here on why validation would not be working at all...?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`=[Requested Posting Date]>=[Date of Request]`
If I'm reading this right, you **don't** want to allow the Requested Posting Date to fall before the Date of Request. The validation fails only if the formula evaluates to `FALSE`. With your formula:
`=[Requested Posting Date]<=[Date of Request]`
a Requested Posting Date that falls before the Date of Request will evaluate to `TRUE`. Earlier dates have lower values.

You can confirm this is the issue by attempting three test cases: date before, date after, and same date.

Comment: Awesome that seemed to work for the most part, thank you so much for your help, my next question would be how can I set it so that they cannot choose a date in the past on the Date of Request field? Right now they could choose say July 15th and set it for being done on the 16th but that is in the past and I need them to be only able to set it for Todays date of the 16th and so on for each coming day without someone being able to change it?

Comment: You could use =[Date of Request]>=Today() , but then you'll get errors if you try to edit the item for another reason tomorrow, unless you push out the Date of Request whenever you edit. Since I don't think you want that, try =[Date of Request]>=Created . I think you'll have to add this to the list validation formula as well, so put both conditions in an AND function. The format would be =AND(TRUE,TRUE).

Comment: Where would I add the =[Date of Request]>=Created and the =AND(TRUE,TRUE) would I put those in the column validation area for each of the [Requested Posting Date] and [Date of Request] or would I put them under the validation settings where I put the last bit of code you gave me, a litte confused? I am a little new to Sharepoint so I am still trying to figure everything out... Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: Or, you could add some type of Request Status column, and place this second check inside an IF function so that it only checks the Date of Request if the status is "New".

Comment: It would all be one formula in the list validation. So it would look like: =AND([Requested Posting Date]>=[Date of Request],IF([Request Status]="New",[Date of Request]>=Today(),TRUE))

Comment: I am getting this error now when I try to add this to List settings ---> Validation Settings --> Formula area.  "The formula refers to a column that does not exist.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column."

Comment: I think the column missing is the [Request Status], what could I put in place of that to make the statement work and not get an error, I don't have the request status column I guess on my site?

Comment: If you're using my last suggestion, you'll have to create the "Request Status" column first. Make it a choice column with whatever list of options makes sense, and set the default value to New. Then when you go to edit a list item on a later day, just make sure the status isn't "New" anymore, to prevent it checking the Date of Request against the current date again.

Comment: Okay I will see what I can do with all of this and see if I can get something to work for me over here, thanks for your help Dan!

Comment: Hey Dan i am back at this form and have a new issue, here is my formula: =AND([Requested Posting Date]>=[Date of Request]+1,IF([Date of Request]="New",[Date of Request]>=TODAY(),TRUE)), if they choose today's date they have to choose at least One (+1 day) into the future and everything is working there, but they can choose a past date which is causing some issues, how would I go about setting up the formula above that I am currently using to only allow you to choose today's date and nothing in the past, let me know how I would set it up so they can't choose past dates with the formula above...

Comment: @SchellShockDesigns Looks like your original problem, *requiring* `Requested Posting Date` *to be greater than* `Date of Request`, is solved, isn't it? As for *preventing users from choosing a date in the past for* `Date of Request`, that would be a **[different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, consider posting it separately.

Comment: Yes the first formula works, just gotta figure out how to prevent them from choosing a date in the past, I created a new question on this here: http://mbeweb.mbe.com/sub_af/lc/Documents/af_tupss_2016_conv_registration_report.pdf, let me know what you think of there responses and what I might do to incorporate it with my current formula, thanks for your help Dan!

Comment: I think you might have pasted the wrong link?